# How to add a decimal button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

How to add a decimal button.
My code for entering numbers:

```
number = number *10 + (int)[sender tag];
display2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10g",number];
```

And my code for decimal numbers.

```
NSString *currentText = display2.text;
if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
    display2.text = [display2.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];

}
```

How this work?! enter 12 and press decimal . and press number 3 = 123 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are getting 123 rather than 12.3 is in your code for the other buttons (not the decimal button). Although I would go with range.location==NSNotFound rather than range.length==0 for adding the decimal, that is not the problem.

The problem is that you are doing number*10 + [sender tag]. Now lets say you enter 1, then 2, then decimal. The "number" will be 12., which is 12. Now, when you multiply it by 10 and add 3, you get 12*10+3 = 120+3 = 123.

What you want to do to get the actual number that you want (12.3) is to instead, use:

```
display2.text = [display2.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
```

In order to get rid of a zero that it is at the beginning of the string, you can do:

```
if ([display.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
}
else {
    display2.text = [display2.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
}
```

Comment: But now i press 1 and result  = 01 :) why?!

Comment: To get rid of that, do `if([display2.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];` and then put the original that I posted in an else. I will update the answer to add this.

Comment: what is the text before you enter 1?

Comment: -(IBAction)Enter_number:(id)sender
{
    
    display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
    
    
    if ([display.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
    }
    else {
        display2.text = [display.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]];
    }
    
 }
If enter 1 = 011

Comment: The reason is that you are adding the text before the if statement as well. Remove everything in the method that is before the `if([display.text isEqualToString:@"0"])`.

Comment: aaaa work))))))) thanks

Comment: how put this value in the "number"

Comment: after you set the text, you can do `number = [display.text floatValue];`

Comment: my "number" this double) => number = [display.text doublevalue];
works)thanks